# Prevent jQuery ContextMenu Submenu Items Size Increase on Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using this jQuery contextMenu: https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/.

I have created a menu with a submenu. When I access the submenu items on mobile Safari or Chrome, the size of the menu items doubles and is cut off on the page.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried setting the CSS properties:

```
text-size-adjust: none !important;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
```

I have also tried:

```
text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
```

But this continues to happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use media query to adjust the size of `ContextMenu` and `SubMenu`

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// you can use 
.submenu {
   @media (max-width: 575.98px) { 
      font-size: 10px;
      // some other properties you prefer to change to on small screens
   }
}
```

for more details [media queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/)

Comment: Ended up using .context-menu-item span. Worked like a charm!